# How to find out unique values and number of unique values in a column in a dataset in Orange?

Tags: anaconda, data-science, data-mining, orange, unique-values

How to find out unique values and number of unique values in a column in a dataset in Orange? I have looked in the widgets Data Info and Feature Statistics, this information is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the "Pivot Table" widget. Configure your pivot table with "Rows" =  and you will see all unique values of your columns as rows.